# What did R.H.M. stand for?

Tags: history, books

I have a number of old chess books published by R.H.M. Press. I am curious as to whether "R.H.M." are the initials of something or someone, and if so, what?

As I understand it, R.H.M. Press was the brainchild of Sidney Fried, and Burt Hochberg was the chief editor of many of the books.  Unfortunately, neither of them is still alive.  I found a [short article](https://go.gale.com/ps/anonymous?id=GALE|A69653067) by Hochberg in the Summer 2000 issue of *Publishing Research Quarterly* entitled "An imperfect visionary," which gives some interesting historical information about R.H.M. Press, but no hint of what R.H.M. might stand for, if anything.

None of the possibilities listed by [The Free Dictionary](https://acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/RHM) looks plausible to me.

Comment: My guess is it stood for 3 people's names, but wasn't actually expanded. If it helps someone, I found this link with a bunch of books published by RHM: https://books.google.com/books?id=Wew8AQAAIAAJ&pg=PA1173&lpg=PA1173&dq=ISBN+0-89058-025-1&source=bl&ots=0YYAvbj9mg&sig=ACfU3U2WxS_-UCekPAeBeZv0oYKQWKlkiw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjSjfi3ysbpAhVX_J4KHRsMBSkQ6AEwAHoECBEQAQ#v=onepage&q=ISBN%200-89058-025-1&f=false

Comment: Just a guess:  Random House Manuscript(s).

Answer (score 6):

Well, let's take Random House off the table right away, as RHM Press was a division of RHM Associates of Delaware, Inc. which lists Sydney Fried as Publisher. The California Secretary of State system lists an RHM Publishing as a "Doing Business As" name for RHM Associates.

Unfortunately, No list of officers.

There's a blurb in the beginning of San Antonio 1972 (the first book RHM published) that talks a little bit about the venture, but no details. Since the most likely RHM Associates of Delaware I can find is an investment firm, I lean towards the idea the RHM name came from the folks that supplied the money to start it.

Comment: The only other associated name I could find, was the name of a sales manager from R.H.M Press in a blog post from 2007: https://nezhmet.wordpress.com/category/rhm-press/    Possibly the only way to find out more, would be to try to contact someone working for them or relatives...

Comment: FWIW, Sidney Fried's "Fortune Building In The 70's" shares the typical cover designs from RHM of those days, so it may be reasonable to assume the RHM Associates was a firm he worked for, perhaps owned. David Levy was an Editor for some of their early books, and he's still around.

Comment: Thanks for this. The Hochberg article says that Fried arranged for virtually all his personal assets to be owned by a corporation, so it wouldn't surprise me if R.H.M. Associates was essentially just Sidney Fried. I'm beginning to think that R.H.M. didn't stand for anything, or if it did, that it was something Fried kept to himself.

Answer (score 1):

```
Edit: This answer is most likely wrong.
```

I think @Mike Jones was really close here: Googling RHM Press brings up the publisher "Random House" (which is fused with Penguin Books).

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_House), *Penguin Random House* started a Joint Venture with the italian company *Arnoldo Mondadori Editore* which is called... **Random House Mondadori**.

I'd suspect that this is indeed the R.H.M. press you were looking for. The group was eventually renamed in 2012, which might explain the absence of any further mentions.

Comment: Thanks for this. But it sounds wrong to me. First off, Random House Mondadori appears to have started in 2001. R.H.M. Press was around in the 1970s. Second, in Hochberg's article, he makes it clear that R.H.M. Press was an independent venture of Fried's, not an offshoot of a giant like Random House.